# Rails 4 Migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I had a table posts with column content of string type(255), when i migrate changes,to change type of string to text,it really change that type,but i get text(255) what does nothing.What im must to do to get such result :

```
TINYTEXT, TEXT, MEDIUMTEXT, LONGTEXT2 | :limit => 1 to 4294967296 (default = 65536)2
```

p.s. on my localmachine i can create posts of any long and type of string,but on heroku i get

```
PG::Error: ERROR: value is too long for type character variyng(255)
```

my _change_datatypes_on_posts_from_string_to_text.rb

```
class ChangeDatatypeOnPostsFromStringToText < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :posts, :content, :text
    change_column :posts, :title, :text
    change_column :users, :name, :text
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using the limit attribute...

eg : "change_column :posts, :content, :text, limit: nil".

On Postgres, a :string, limit:nil is effectively synonymous with :text.

Comment: thanks,it helped,but after migration on heroku i still get
PG::Error: ERROR: value is too long for type character variyng(255)
you dont know why?